# How to make count down timer with completion handler in swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

Currently I am trying to Create a 3...2...1... Go! type of count down where right after Go! is stated an action occurs however the option to use the completion handler for `Timer.scheduleTimer` doesn't have the ability to countdown from what I understand?

As of now I can count down from 3 but don't know how to invalidate the timer at Go! and perform an action

```
var seconds = 3
var countDownTimer = Timer()

func startCountDown() {
  countDownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(TrackActivityVC.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {

  seconds -= 1
  print(seconds)
}

// Not sure how to use this code to create a countdown, as it doesn't seem possible with this method

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: someInterval, repeats: false) {

}
```

Thus the question is How to make count down timer with completion handler.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is how to create a countdown timer using the trailing closure syntax:

```
var seconds = 3

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
    self.seconds -= 1
    if self.seconds == 0 {
        print("Go!")
        timer.invalidate()
    } else {
        print(self.seconds)
    }
}
```

---

Here is a better version that invalidates the timer when the `viewController` is deinitialized.  It uses `[weak self]` to avoid hanging on to the `viewController` if it closes:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var seconds = 3
    var myTimer: Timer?

    func startCountdown() {
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            self?.seconds -= 1
            if self?.seconds == 0 {
                print("Go!")
                timer.invalidate()
            } else if let seconds = self?.seconds {
                print(seconds)
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        // ViewController going away.  Kill the timer.
        myTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```